# having trouble updating value serialized array in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, serialization

Here what I does

```
 - extract my serialize array from databse
 - deserialize it
 - change the value
 - after changing I serialize it
 - then write it back to MYSQL database table.
```

But Im having trouble writing it back to MYSQL database table

```
$myarray = Array
(
    [dogname] => Array
        (
            [0] => white
            [1] => zeon
            [2] => imao
        )

    [visit] => Array
        (
            [0] => once
            [1] => twice
            [2] => twice
        )
}
```

I save it database with this way into my table `serialize($myarray)`

now I extract it and unserialize

```
$unserializearray = unserialize($myserialarray); 

then search for array value to change and back to table

$keys = array_keys($unserializearray['dogname'], 'imao', true);
foreach($keys as $key)
{
    // find dogname imao and change its visit to once
    $unserializearray['visit'][$key] = "once";


$update = serialize($unserializearray);

//save the update    
mysql_query("UPDATE dogdetails SET checkup = '$update'
WHERE dogid = '1'");
}
```

but it dont save right into mysql do I miss something in code?

Comment: Why doesn't it save right? If "once" is a string it should be quoted.

Comment: I added a qoutes but not working too

Answer (score 0):

First of all this can't work, if something in your array has a single quote in it, so you need to do

```
$update=mysql_real_escap_string(serialize($unserializearray),$dbhandle);
```

or friends.

More importantly, your database design seem heavily flawed to me: As has been said many, many times here, you should not store more than one value in a field, if you want to access them seperately. In your case, you store three dogs with their vists, but you want to access them seperately - this is what your code does.

Answer (score 0):

As Eugen said, there are many things wrong with your code.

Except all that, does this code works any better:

```
$unserializearray = unserialize($myserialarray); 

then search for array value to change and back to table

$keys = array_keys($unserializearray['dogname'], 'imao', true);
foreach($keys as $key)
{
    // find dogname imao and change its visit to once
    $unserializearray['visit'][$key] = "once";
}

$update = mysql_real_escap_string(serialize($unserializearray));

//save the update    
mysql_query("UPDATE dogdetails SET checkup = '$update' WHERE dogid = '1'");
```